# Use of undeclared type 'Firebase'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know this is one of the most asked question but still couldn't find the problem.

I tried updating pod but still this error.

```
import Firebase

public static func createUrlToGetMessages(threadId id: String) -> Firebase {
    return Firebase(url: FIREBASE_BASE_REF)
        .childByAppendingPath("chats")
        .childByAppendingPath(id)
        .childByAppendingPath("messages")
}
public static func createUrlToGetOneMessageRef(threadId threadId: String, messageId messageId: String) -> Firebase {
    return Firebase(url: FIREBASE_BASE_REF)
        .childByAppendingPath("chats")
        .childByAppendingPath(threadId)
        .childByAppendingPath("messages")
        .childByAppendingPath(messageId)
}
```

[image]

Comment: No error when you import Firebase?

Comment: No. No error shown while 'import Firebase'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are using [old deprecated version](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/quickstart.html) of Firebase.

Read [the new docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start) for the setup details.

Your code should be like this:

```
import Firebase

var ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

public static func createUrlToGetMessages(threadId id: String) -> FIRDatabaseReference {
    return ref.child("chats").child(id).child("messages")
}

public static func createUrlToGetOneMessageRef(threadId: String, messageId: String) -> FIRDatabaseReference {
    return ref.child("chats").child(threadId).child("messages").child(messageId)
}
```